# Apache Mesos Getting Started -- Python Framework Example -- Expected: 'data with a \x00 byte' error

Tags: mesos

I'm very new to Apache Mesos and was getting acquainted by following the instructions on the [Mesos Getting Started](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/) page using Mesos version `1.0.0`.

I followed the "Downloading Mesos" and "Building Mesos (POSIX)" instructions on Ubuntu Linux and compiled Mesos into a userspace build directory: `$BUILD`.

Afterwards, I attempted to try out the "Run Python framework" in the "Examples" section as a non-root user using 3 terminals and a user write-able log directory: `$MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR`.

Running this example gave me the following error:

```
Task 0 is in state TASK_FAILED
The update data did not match!
  Expected: 'data with a \x00 byte'
  Actual:   ''
Failed to call scheduler's statusUpdate
```

What am I doing wrong?

Below are the commands I used on 3 separate terminals, and abridged outputs I observed on each respective terminal.

### Terminal Inputs

#### Terminal 1: (Mesos Master)

```
cd $BUILD
./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=$MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR/var/lib/mesos
```

#### Terminal 2: (Mesos Agent)

```
cd $BUILD
./bin/mesos-agent.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --work_dir=$MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR/var/lib/mesos
```

#### Terminal 3: (Task Job / Run Python Framework)

```
cd $BUILD
./src/examples/python/test-framework 127.0.0.1:5050
```

### Terminal Outputs

#### Terminal 1: (Mesos Master)

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0810 05:55:32.932193 21522 main.cpp:263] Build: 2016-08-09 19:23:08 by me
I0810 05:55:32.932521 21522 main.cpp:264] Version: 1.0.0
I0810 05:55:32.944061 21522 main.cpp:370] Using 'HierarchicalDRF' allocator

<snip>

I0810 05:56:00.718638 21539 master.cpp:1847] The newly elected leader is master@127.0.0.1:5050 with id 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936
I0810 05:56:00.718727 21539 master.cpp:1860] Elected as the leading master!

<snip>

I0810 05:56:13.194939 21541 master.cpp:2424] Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'Test Framework (Python)' at scheduler
I0810 05:56:13.195627 21541 master.cpp:2500] Subscribing framework Test Framework (Python) with checkpointing enabled and capabilities [  ]
I0810 05:56:13.200559 21543 hierarchical.cpp:271] Added framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 

<snip>

W0810 05:56:26.117612 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 3 of framework 6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117663 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 2 of framework 6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117679 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 1 of framework 6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117693 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 0 of framework 6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117714 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 3 of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117729 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 2 of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117743 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 1 of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117756 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 0 of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117774 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 3 of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117789 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 2 of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117804 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 1 of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.117816 21536 master.cpp:6567] Possibly orphaned completed task 0 of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001 that ran on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:26.118463 21536 master.cpp:4872] Re-registered agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox) with cpus(*):4; mem(*):4950; disk(*):9.43713e+08; ports(*):[31000-32000]
I0810 05:56:26.118600 21536 master.cpp:4940] Sending updated checkpointed resources  to agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:26.118614 21537 hierarchical.cpp:478] Added agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 (linuxbox) with cpus(*):4; mem(*):4950; disk(*):9.43713e+08; ports(*):[31000-32000] (allocated: )
I0810 05:56:26.121769 21536 master.cpp:5709] Sending 1 offers to framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580
I0810 05:56:26.122695 21538 master.cpp:5002] Received update of agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox) with total oversubscribed resources
I0810 05:56:26.123118 21538 hierarchical.cpp:542] Agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 (linuxbox) updated with oversubscribed resources  (total: cpus(*):4; mem(*):4950; disk(*):9.43713e+08; ports(*):[31000-32000], allocated: cpus(*):4; mem(*):4950; disk(*):9.43713e+08; ports(*):[31000-32000])
I0810 05:56:26.131975 21538 master.cpp:3342] Processing ACCEPT call for offers: [ 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-O0 ] on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox) for framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580
W0810 05:56:26.135907 21537 validation.cpp:647] Executor default for task 0 uses less CPUs (None) than the minimum required (0.01). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
W0810 05:56:26.135973 21537 validation.cpp:659] Executor default for task 0 uses less memory (None) than the minimum required (32MB). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
I0810 05:56:26.136854 21537 master.cpp:7439] Adding task 0 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:26.136960 21537 master.cpp:3831] Launching task 0 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.138489 21537 validation.cpp:647] Executor default for task 1 uses less CPUs (None) than the minimum required (0.01). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
W0810 05:56:26.138540 21537 validation.cpp:659] Executor default for task 1 uses less memory (None) than the minimum required (32MB). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
I0810 05:56:26.138764 21537 master.cpp:7439] Adding task 1 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:26.138855 21537 master.cpp:3831] Launching task 1 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.139731 21537 validation.cpp:647] Executor default for task 2 uses less CPUs (None) than the minimum required (0.01). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
W0810 05:56:26.139770 21537 validation.cpp:659] Executor default for task 2 uses less memory (None) than the minimum required (32MB). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
I0810 05:56:26.139966 21537 master.cpp:7439] Adding task 2 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:26.140054 21537 master.cpp:3831] Launching task 2 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:26.140861 21537 validation.cpp:647] Executor default for task 3 uses less CPUs (None) than the minimum required (0.01). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
W0810 05:56:26.140897 21537 validation.cpp:659] Executor default for task 3 uses less memory (None) than the minimum required (32MB). Please update your executor, as this will be mandatory in future releases.
I0810 05:56:26.141103 21537 master.cpp:7439] Adding task 3 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:26.141196 21537 master.cpp:3831] Launching task 3 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)

<snip>leveldb logs</snip>

I0810 05:56:27.633244 21543 master.cpp:5249] Executor 'default' of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox): exited with status 1
I0810 05:56:27.633337 21543 master.cpp:6928] Removing executor 'default' with resources  of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:27.654547 21540 master.cpp:5147] Status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 8d5cb564-0ee1-4ade-aa2f-51980f4eb385) for task 0 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 from agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:27.654714 21540 master.cpp:5195] Forwarding status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 8d5cb564-0ee1-4ade-aa2f-51980f4eb385) for task 0 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000
I0810 05:56:27.655238 21540 master.cpp:6833] Updating the state of task 0 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (latest state: TASK_FAILED, status update state: TASK_FAILED)
I0810 05:56:27.670207 21540 master.cpp:5147] Status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: ca90acb2-0da2-4933-ab8b-5142072a3b68) for task 1 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 from agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:27.670295 21540 master.cpp:5195] Forwarding status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: ca90acb2-0da2-4933-ab8b-5142072a3b68) for task 1 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000
I0810 05:56:27.670701 21540 master.cpp:6833] Updating the state of task 1 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (latest state: TASK_FAILED, status update state: TASK_FAILED)
I0810 05:56:27.688217 21539 master.cpp:1284] Framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580 disconnected
I0810 05:56:27.688283 21539 master.cpp:2725] Disconnecting framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580
I0810 05:56:27.688330 21539 master.cpp:2749] Deactivating framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580
E0810 05:56:27.688390 21544 process.cpp:2105] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 9: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0810 05:56:27.688524 21539 master.cpp:1297] Giving framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580 0ns to failover
I0810 05:56:27.688583 21543 hierarchical.cpp:382] Deactivated framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000
I0810 05:56:27.689872 21540 master.cpp:5561] Framework failover timeout, removing framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580
I0810 05:56:27.689924 21540 master.cpp:6296] Removing framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (Test Framework (Python)) at scheduler-2c565680-3f64-4ee3-8bbb-231addd11944@192.168.2.3:60580
I0810 05:56:27.690450 21540 master.cpp:6833] Updating the state of task 3 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (latest state: TASK_KILLED, status update state: TASK_KILLED)
I0810 05:56:27.690906 21540 master.cpp:6899] Removing task 3 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:27.691269 21540 master.cpp:6833] Updating the state of task 2 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (latest state: TASK_KILLED, status update state: TASK_KILLED)
I0810 05:56:27.691507 21540 master.cpp:6899] Removing task 2 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:27.691673 21540 master.cpp:6833] Updating the state of task 1 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (latest state: TASK_FAILED, status update state: TASK_KILLED)
I0810 05:56:27.691707 21540 master.cpp:6899] Removing task 1 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
I0810 05:56:27.691895 21540 master.cpp:6833] Updating the state of task 0 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 (latest state: TASK_FAILED, status update state: TASK_KILLED)
I0810 05:56:27.691926 21540 master.cpp:6899] Removing task 0 with resources cpus(*):1; mem(*):128 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 on agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox)
W0810 05:56:27.693068 21540 master.cpp:5140] Ignoring status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: e202f922-ff82-4852-9393-02bc762edf8b) for task 2 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 from agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox) because the framework is unknown
I0810 05:56:27.693373 21541 hierarchical.cpp:333] Removed framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000
W0810 05:56:27.708871 21541 master.cpp:5140] Ignoring status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: e28a2332-e6ef-458e-81a8-ea8bd8edce19) for task 3 of framework 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000 from agent f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0 at slave(1)@192.168.2.3:5051 (linuxbox) because the framework is unknown
```

#### Terminal 2: (Mesos Agent)

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0810 05:55:36.992377 21562 main.cpp:243] Build: 2016-08-09 19:23:08 by me
I0810 05:55:36.992777 21562 main.cpp:244] Version: 1.0.0
I0810 05:55:37.012877 21562 containerizer.cpp:196] Using isolation: posix/cpu,posix/mem,filesystem/posix,network/cni
W0810 05:55:37.018576 21562 backend.cpp:75] Failed to create 'bind' backend: BindBackend requires root privileges
I0810 05:55:37.026435 21562 main.cpp:434] Starting Mesos agent
I0810 05:55:37.028482 21582 slave.cpp:198] Agent started on 1)@192.168.2.3:5051
I0810 05:55:37.028508 21582 slave.cpp:199] Flags at startup: --appc_simple_discovery_uri_prefix="http://" --appc_store_dir="/tmp/mesos/store/appc" --authenticate_http_readonly="false" --authenticate_http_readwrite="false" --authenticatee="crammd5" --authentication_backoff_factor="1secs" --authorizer="local" --cgroups_cpu_enable_pids_and_tids_count="false" --cgroups_enable_cfs="false" --cgroups_hierarchy="/sys/fs/cgroup" --cgroups_limit_swap="false" --cgroups_root="mesos" --container_disk_watch_interval="15secs" --containerizers="mesos" --default_role="*" --disk_watch_interval="1mins" --docker="docker" --docker_kill_orphans="true" --docker_registry="https://registry-1.docker.io" --docker_remove_delay="6hrs" --docker_socket="/var/run/docker.sock" --docker_stop_timeout="0ns" --docker_store_dir="/tmp/mesos/store/docker" --docker_volume_checkpoint_dir="/var/run/mesos/isolators/docker/volume" --enforce_container_disk_quota="false" --executor_registration_timeout="1mins" --executor_shutdown_grace_period="5secs" --fetcher_cache_dir="/tmp/mesos/fetch" --fetcher_cache_size="2GB" --frameworks_home="" --gc_delay="1weeks" --gc_disk_headroom="0.1" --hadoop_home="" --help="false" --hostname_lookup="true" --http_authenticators="basic" --http_command_executor="false" --image_provisioner_backend="copy" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --isolation="posix/cpu,posix/mem" --launcher_dir="${MESOS_SRC_DIR}/mesos-1.0.0/build/src" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --master="127.0.0.1:5050" --oversubscribed_resources_interval="15secs" --perf_duration="10secs" --perf_interval="1mins" --port="5051" --qos_correction_interval_min="0ns" --quiet="false" --recover="reconnect" --recovery_timeout="15mins" --registration_backoff_factor="1secs" --revocable_cpu_low_priority="true" --sandbox_directory="/mnt/mesos/sandbox" --strict="true" --switch_user="true" --systemd_enable_support="true" --systemd_runtime_directory="/run/systemd/system" --version="false" --work_dir="${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos"
I0810 05:55:37.036922 21582 slave.cpp:519] Agent resources: cpus(*):4; mem(*):4950; disk(*):9.43713e+08; ports(*):[31000-32000]
I0810 05:55:37.037050 21582 slave.cpp:527] Agent attributes: [  ]
I0810 05:55:37.037096 21582 slave.cpp:532] Agent hostname: linuxbox
I0810 05:55:37.057514 21579 state.cpp:57] Recovering state from '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta'
W0810 05:55:37.157933 21579 state.cpp:544] Failed to find executor libprocess pid/http marker file
I0810 05:55:37.169766 21581 slave.cpp:4870] Recovering framework 6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000
I0810 05:55:37.170205 21581 slave.cpp:5798] Recovering executor 'default' of framework 6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000
I0810 05:55:37.175171 21584 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000/executors/default/runs/919bb8b4-70aa-48e0-ae41-d48b7752b36c' for gc 6.98397945710519days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.175750 21581 slave.cpp:4281] Cleaning up framework 6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000
I0810 05:55:37.175777 21584 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000/executors/default/runs/919bb8b4-70aa-48e0-ae41-d48b7752b36c' for gc 6.98397945307852days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.175894 21578 status_update_manager.cpp:282] Closing status update streams for framework 6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000
I0810 05:55:37.175906 21584 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000/executors/default' for gc 6.98397945185185days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.175981 21584 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000/executors/default' for gc 6.98397945105185days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.176434 21580 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000' for gc 6.99999795937481days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.177531 21582 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000' for gc 6.99999794667852days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.177633 21581 slave.cpp:4870] Recovering framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002
I0810 05:55:37.177726 21581 slave.cpp:5798] Recovering executor 'default' of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002
I0810 05:55:37.180641 21585 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002/executors/default/runs/e8afac0d-a20e-499b-8e0e-6c64d64f0cdb' for gc 6.71944235485926days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.180917 21585 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002/executors/default/runs/e8afac0d-a20e-499b-8e0e-6c64d64f0cdb' for gc 6.71944235118222days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.181032 21585 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002/executors/default' for gc 6.71944235001185days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.181112 21585 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002/executors/default' for gc 6.71944234915556days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.181126 21581 slave.cpp:4281] Cleaning up framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002
I0810 05:55:37.181241 21584 status_update_manager.cpp:282] Closing status update streams for framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002
I0810 05:55:37.181540 21578 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002' for gc 6.99999789952593days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.181849 21581 slave.cpp:4870] Recovering framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001
I0810 05:55:37.181891 21584 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002' for gc 6.99999789593778days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.181915 21581 slave.cpp:5798] Recovering executor 'default' of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001
I0810 05:55:37.184018 21584 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001/executors/default/runs/a262d43a-52d4-4469-b264-1a143a66f147' for gc 6.71397935287111days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.184191 21582 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001/executors/default/runs/a262d43a-52d4-4469-b264-1a143a66f147' for gc 6.71397935029037days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.184459 21582 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001/executors/default' for gc 6.71397934912days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.184531 21581 slave.cpp:4281] Cleaning up framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001
I0810 05:55:37.184554 21582 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001/executors/default' for gc 6.71397934666667days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.184633 21582 status_update_manager.cpp:282] Closing status update streams for framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001
I0810 05:55:37.185003 21582 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001' for gc 6.9999978598963days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.185269 21581 slave.cpp:4870] Recovering framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000
I0810 05:55:37.185309 21582 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001' for gc 6.99999785635556days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.185339 21581 slave.cpp:5798] Recovering executor 'default' of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000
I0810 05:55:37.187397 21580 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000/executors/default/runs/af8c10fa-1125-46f3-baa4-2ccf63fc50ae' for gc 6.70797236873778days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.187611 21584 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000/executors/default/runs/af8c10fa-1125-46f3-baa4-2ccf63fc50ae' for gc 6.70797236678222days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.187702 21584 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000/executors/default' for gc 6.70797236584296days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.187732 21581 slave.cpp:4281] Cleaning up framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000
I0810 05:55:37.187780 21584 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000/executors/default' for gc 6.70797236505778days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.187798 21585 status_update_manager.cpp:282] Closing status update streams for framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000
I0810 05:55:37.188364 21582 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000' for gc 6.99999782332148days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.188454 21582 gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '${MESOS_BASE_VAR_DIR}/tmp/var/lib/mesos/meta/slaves/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-S0/frameworks/f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000' for gc 6.99999781941037days in the future
I0810 05:55:37.192026 21582 status_update_manager.cpp:200] Recovering status update manager
I0810 05:55:37.192095 21582 status_update_manager.cpp:208] Recovering executor 'default' of framework 6883bc82-edc4-4fb5-8e19-bd1937ab4509-0000
I0810 05:55:37.192287 21582 status_update_manager.cpp:208] Recovering executor 'default' of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0002
I0810 05:55:37.192469 21582 status_update_manager.cpp:208] Recovering executor 'default' of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0001
I0810 05:55:37.192637 21582 status_update_manager.cpp:208] Recovering executor 'default' of framework f8d8dd51-7098-436e-94c8-42dfb0db9fae-0000
I0810 05:55:37.205670 21583 slave.cpp:4782] Finished recovery
```

#### Terminal 3: (Task Job / Run Python Framework)

```
I0810 05:55:55.672643 21606 sched.cpp:226] Version: 1.0.0
I0810 05:55:55.686266 21673 sched.cpp:330] New master detected at master@127.0.0.1:5050
I0810 05:55:55.686885 21673 sched.cpp:341] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I0810 05:56:13.201035 21680 sched.cpp:743] Framework registered with 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000
Registered with framework ID 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-0000
Received offer 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-O0 with cpus: 4.0 and mem: 4950.0
Launching task 0 using offer 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-O0
Launching task 1 using offer 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-O0
Launching task 2 using offer 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-O0
Launching task 3 using offer 10500b16-aed1-421a-bcd6-44d82874e936-O0
Task 0 is in state TASK_FAILED
The update data did not match!
  Expected: 'data with a \x00 byte'
  Actual:   ''
Failed to call scheduler's statusUpdate
```

Answer (score 2):

It confused me a lot, finally i got that work by using `sudo` privilege.